403 Forbidden Error when fetching content from a URL hosted in Zendesk
When I try following python code to fetch content from a URL hosted in Zendesk, I get following 403 Forbidden Error:
Python Code:
url = 'https://support.abc.com/hc...'
html_content = fetch_content(url)
if html_content:
    text_content = html_to_text(html_content.decode('utf-8'))
    # Output directory and file name
    output_pdf_file = os.path.join('output', 'output.pdf')
    if not os.path.exists('output'):
        os.makedirs('output')
        save_text_to_pdf(text_content, output_pdf_file)
        print(f'PDF saved to {output_pdf_file}')

Error:
Error fetching https://support.abc.com/hc....: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

What can I try next, especially in the code part, as I don't want to change any configuration on the Zendesk side?

Most likely the website you're trying to access has some sort of anti-crawling measures in place which are rejecting your request

Pretty clear error? You are forbidden from accessing that URL. If you need to (legitimately) interface with zendesk, use one of the python libraries?

To fetch the public articles through API you can use these routes:
https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/help_center/help-center-api/articles/#list-articles . No API key is needed.
If the article you are trying to fetch is private, you will only be able to fetch the content if you have the API key of the zendesk instance.
